# java.nio and writing non-blocking Scala code

Tags: scala, scalability, nio, nonblocking

Would there be anything at all non-blocking in code like follows for writing to a file, just by merit of its use of java.nio?

```
def writeOutputFile(fileText: String, outDir: String, fileName: String) { 
  import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths, Files}
  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

  Files.write(Paths.get(outDir + "/" + fileName), fileText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```

Or would you need to wrap this code with a promise and future in order to write a file without blocking? if wrapped like that, would that not produce another thread that blocks during this `.write`?

Thanks!

Comment: As I understand it it will still block caller of the function. If you want it to be async you need to wrap it in a future or use AsynchronousFileChannel channel interface.

Comment: You can set it up so that it doesn't block, but you risk not ensuring that it terminates, or that you don't catch an error, unless you wrap it in a future like Lionel said, and either wait or await the future's fulfillment.

Comment: Thought so, but, what at all is async about nio itself, in this scenario then? does it do anything that java.io wouldn't, in a file `.write`?

Answer (score 1):

java.nio by its own merit does not provide any non-blocking benefits. The standard `FileChannel` is still a blocking API. In order to access its non-blocking capabilities, you would have to use `AsynchronousFileChannel`.

*Note:* Be careful not to mistake the read/write methods providing a java `Future` as being a useful async abstraction, since with that `Future` you still have to block to be notified of completion. It is only better than synchronous I/O if you have a bunch of java `Future` instances that you are waiting on.

For a truly async I/O API, you should wrap the read/write methods that accept a `CompletionHandler` with a scala Future, so you can be notified asynchronously of I/O completions. (See [shifter.io](https://github.com/alexandru/shifter/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shifter/io/AsyncFileChannel.scala) for an example)